# admob view white gap at bottom on test ads

Tags: android, admob

In my app, i use fragments. I initialize the adview in my main activity. Each fragment has a listview with an admob view at the bottom end of the listview. Test Ads show up in my first fragment but when i navigate to another fragment although i tried to use `destroy()` when `onPause()` function of the fragment is triggered, there is a white gap at the bottom of the listview at the new fragment i landed! I haven't created any adviews in the new fragment! Any thoughts why is this happening?

Any help appreciated!

This is my homefragment.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/homelistview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/admobviewDescription"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homelistview"
    >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

UPDATE

I found this page  https://developers.google.com/admob/android/custom-events
which mentions the following. Anyone knows if this means that test ads cant be paused?

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        // The sample ad network doesn't have an onPause method, so does nothing.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how it should be done. Onpause() can be used by the way in test ads do not know what the sample ad network is. So this is the code you should use to remove this white gap. Actually you have to remove the adview you created from the parentlayout in order to remove the view and the white gap and then add a new adview. I tried also adview.removeallviews() but didnt work. Only this code worked.

```
// Remove the ad keeping the attributes
        AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) ad.getLayoutParams();
        ConstraintLayout parentLayout = (ConstraintLayout) ad.getParent();
        parentLayout.removeView(ad);

// Re-initialise the ad
        ad.destroy();
        ad = new AdView(this);
        ad.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

       //test ads
        ad.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        ad.setId(R.id.adView1);
        ad.setLayoutParams(lp);
        parentLayout.addView(ad);

// Re-fetch add and check successful load
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        ad.loadAd(adRequest);
```